# Unable to start minikube on MacOS

Tags: macos, kubernetes, minikube

I'm getting below error when I try to run the minikube after downloading its binary:-

```
❌  Exiting due to GUEST_START: wait: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH="/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.22.3:$PATH" kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap,NumCPU,Mem,SystemVerification,FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables": Process exited with status 1
stdout:
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.22.3
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/var/lib/minikube/certs"
[certs] Using existing ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing apiserver certificate and key on disk

stderr:
    [WARNING Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap
    [WARNING Service-Kubelet]: kubelet service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable kubelet.service'
W0304 05:40:42.096000    3744 certs.go:489] WARNING: could not validate bounds for certificate apiserver-kubelet-client: the certificate has expired: NotBefore: 2020-06-29 07:35:45 +0000 UTC, NotAfter: 2022-12-10 12:46:24 +0000 UTC
error execution phase certs/apiserver-kubelet-client: [certs] certificate apiserver-kubelet-client not signed by CA certificate ca: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-03-04T05:40:42Z is after 2022-12-10T12:46:24Z
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

I'm referring its official documentation [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/)

It gives a warning that kubelet service is not enabled and suggested to use 'systemctl enable kubelet.service'. I tried below commands but no idea how run the minikube on MacOS:-

```
(base) -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~ » systemctl enable kubelet.service                                                                                                                                                                                                         80 ↵ vinod827@Vinods-MacBook-Pro
zsh: command not found: systemctl
(base) -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~ » launchctl enable kubelet.service                                                                                                                                                                                                        127 ↵ vinod827@Vinods-MacBook-Pro
Unrecognized target specifier.
Usage: launchctl enable <service-target>
<service-target> takes a form of <domain-target>/<service-id>.
Please refer to `man launchctl` for explanation of the <domain-target> specifiers.
(base)
```

Any idea what could be the problem here?

Comment: This sounds like it would be a good fit for the [Minikube Community](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube#community).

Comment: Executing both 'minikube delete' and 'minikube start' has solved the problem for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Executing both `minikube delete` and `minikube start` has solved the problem for me